# Nightwatch - Junit XMl file not being generated after tests are run

Tags: nightwatch.js

The tests are run successfully. The output folder is mentioned in the config file. Yet the Junit XML is not being generated. Here is the nightwatch config file - https://pastebin.com/NiYfJx87

Screenshots are correctly being generated. It is only the xml output which is not generated. Do we have to install junit for the report to be generated?

Also I use mocha as the test runner. Is that the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with what you are trying to do:

1)   Add an options block to the test_runner block in the nightwatch config which will specify the reporter as shown below:

 `test_runner: {
    type: 'mocha',
    options: {
      ui: 'bdd',
      reporter: 'junit',
      timeout: 10000
    }
  }`

2. Note that mocha does not support junit as a reporter.  Xunit is probably the closest.    You can add libraries which will add this.  I do not have experience with them...

https://mochajs.org/#reporters

Libraries which add junit support:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-junit-reporter